# SSL PROTOCOL ERROR on subdomain with Apache on Ubuntu Server 17.04

Tags: ubuntu, website, apache2

I have a domain, I'll use test.nl for example.

Got wordpress running as a virtualhost on the main domain.
Got wikimedia running as a virtualhost on the subdomain: wiki.test.nl

Now I've got another subdomain (vnc.test.nl) that I want to secure with a self signed certificate so the VNC connection is secured.

Ports are correctly forwarded.

Virtualhost file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName vnc.test.nl
   Redirect permanent / https://vnc.test.nl/
</VirtualHost>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
   <VirtualHost *:443>
       ServerName vnc.test.nl
       DocumentRoot /var/www/vnc.test.nl
       DirectoryIndex index.html index.php index.pl index.cgi
       ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
       CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

       SSLEngine on
       SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/server.crt
       SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/server.key

       ProxyPreserveHost On
       ProxyPass / http://10.0.6.4:6080/
       ProxyPassReverse / http://10.0.6.4:6080/
   </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

I've used this guide on how to secure a site with SSL. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-ssl-certificate-on-apache-for-ubuntu-14-04

I get SLL_PROTOCOL_ERROR in my browser. In the apache ERROR log there is this noted:

```
[Tue Nov 14 13:04:05.476933 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 2128] AH01906: vnc.test.nl:443:0 server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == 
TRUE !?)
[Tue Nov 14 13:04:05.497306 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 2132] AH01906: vnc.test.nl:443:0 server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == 
TRUE !?)
[Tue Nov 14 13:04:05.499219 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 2132] AH00163: 
Apache/2.4.25 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.0.2g configured -- resuming normal 
operations
[Tue Nov 14 13:04:05.499241 2017] [core:notice] [pid 2132] AH00094: Command 
line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

Then I tried CertBot, but the only thing I get is:

```
 Server only speaks HTTP, not TLS
```

Even when I remove the listening on port 80 in the virtualhost file.

How do I correct the ssl protocol error?

Answer (score 0):

Seems you installed the wrong file as server certificate. You can read the contents of a cert with `openssl x509 -in server.crt -text`. (If it's not in `pem` format you have to play around with the parameter `-inform`.)

Check your `server.crt` and additional files you might have got from the CA. The right cert must list `vpn.test.nl` as *Subject Alternate Name* and/or as CN. (Nowadays certificates should always contain the *Subject Alternate Name*.)

If you test the right file one of the following lines should occur:

```
    ...
    Subject: CN=vpn.test.nl
    ...
    X509v3 extensions:
        X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
            DNS:vpn.test.nl
    ...
```

PS: You should edit your question and remove your real domain name...even from logs.

Comment: Thanks! I made a new cert, now in the .pem format and edited my virtualhost file. The error logs are gone now, I still get the SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR.

Comment: In the connect log there is this line:

"\x16\x03\x01" 400 0 "-" "-"